# How to download a portion of a YouTube video

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, video, bash-scripting, youtube-dl

I often come across YouTube videos that I need to crop parts from, but these videos can be long and downloading the entire video just to process a small part of them would take too long and be very wasteful.

Despite there being a `youtube-dl` Github issue on this [since 2013](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/622) and there being *some* progress on that front, nothing has yet materialised and as of 2021, this feature remains unavailable.

What other solutions are there to only download the part of the video that I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few days of searching, the best solution I've come across for this so far combines `youtube-dl`'s ability to fetch the internal URLs of a YouTube video's individual streams with `ffmpeg`'s ability to use those streams as input.

---

### The quick (Bash) way

Run the following Bash magic to automatically populate the `video_url` and `audio_url` variables with the internal YouTube URLs for the target link's video and audio streams respectively:

```
# As scary as it looks, perfectly safe to run in a terminal 
{   
   read -r video_url  
   read -r audio_url
} < <(
   youtube-dl --get-url --youtube-skip-dash-manifest https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfnzBYV5fxs
)
```

Lastly, pass the timestamps through to download the portion of the video that you want:

```
# Download 2 minutes of the video between 5 mins in to 7 mins, using timestamps:
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00.00 -to 00:07:00.00 -i "$video_url" -ss 00:05:00.00 -to 00:07:00.00 -i "$audio_url" output.mkv
```

***Or*** if you prefer to crop a duration instead of the time between two timestamps:

```
# Download 2 minutes of the video between 5 mins in to 7 mins, using duration:  
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00.00 -i "$video_url" -ss 00:05:00.00 -i "$audio_url" -t 2:00 output.mkv
```

---

### The manual (non-Bash) way

If you're using any other shell apart from Bash, you'll have to do it the manual way:

Running the following will output YouTube's (very long) internal URLs for your target video's video and audio streams:

```
youtube-dl --get-url --youtube-skip-dash-manifest "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfnzBYV5fxs"
```

Plug in these URLs into the following command, pasting them in place of `<video_url>` and `<audio_url>` respectively:

```
# Download 2 minutes of the video between 5 mins in to 7 mins, using timestamps:
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00.00 -to 00:07:00.00 -i <video_url> -ss 00:05:00.00 -to 00:07:00.00 -i <audio_url> output.mkv
```

***Or*** if you prefer to crop a duration instead of the time between two timestamps:

```
# Download 2 minutes of the video between 5 mins in to 7 mins, using duration:  
ffmpeg -ss 00:05:00.00 -i <video_url> -ss 00:05:00.00 -i <audio_url> -t 2:00 output.mkv
```

Comment: I don't see how anything in your proposed solution is bash-specific. Every modern shell should have some syntax to get a couple arguments from one command's output and plug them into another.

Comment: Yes, and `{ read -r video_url read -r audio_url } < <(` is that syntax for Bash, making it Bash-specific.